# LiveValidation js -- Change Text Message to Image

Tags: javascript

[LiveValidation](http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleHomepage) is a nice little inline form validation plugin.

I'd like to change the text confirmation message to an image.

The line that I edit is:

```
var message = paramsObj.failureMessage || "Must be included in the list!";
```

But when I change Must be... to img src=... it only displays the html text itself, not the image I'm calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would investigate overriding the image css for the given form you want the validation image to show up for.  I don't think this validation package will recognize an image URL, if I understand your attempt correctly.  This would give you the picture message you want, while using the 'customization' point designed by this package's author.

> LiveValidation objects use a few CSS classes to allow you to style up
>   the messages and the form fields based upon whether they are valid or
>   not.
>
> - LV_validation_message - the class that is added to all validation messages
> - LV_valid - the class that is added to a valid message
> - LV_invalid - the class that is added to an invalid message
> - LV_valid_field - the class that is added to a valid field
> - LV_invalid_filed - the class that is added to an invalid field

eg:

```
.LV_invalid {
       /*color:#CC0000;*/
        background-image:url('paper.gif');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll work. I'll just remove the text message and style it up as you suggested. Great suggestion, thanks!